# How can I automate generation of test names from my notes?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, editing

Before writing test cases, I often write descriptions of the tests as comments in the file that will become the test case. Later, I use the descriptions as the names of the tests. For example,

```
// a user can log in
// password is stored in the database
```

becomes

```
function test_a_user_can_log_in() {
    // test code here...
}

function test_password_is_stored_in_the_database() {
    // test code here...
}
```

I usually rewrite the sentences and insert the underscores manually, but of course there must be a better way.

Is there some kind of regular expression, `sed` command, shell pipeline, etc. that can automate this?

Comment: If you use an editor like `vim` or `emacs`, there is probably a way to define a function or macro that will do this "natively".

Comment: Unfortunately I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`, you can use something like

```
sed '\|//|{ s/ /_/g; s|//|test|; s/$/ () \{\
  # test code here\
\}/; }' tmp.sh
```

Comment: Bravo for the use of `sed`.

Comment: So just to make sure I got it straight: first it finds lines beginning with `//`, then replaces spaces with underscores, `//` with `test`, and slaps the function body on the end. Correct?

Comment: Yes. I suspect this could be made shorter, but `sed` is not my strong point.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `awk` which you would test that the first field is `"//"` and if so, write the record out as a function name with the commented body, e.g.

```
awk '$1~/\/\// {
    $1 = "test"
    gsub(/ /,"_")
    print "function "$0"() {\n    // test code here...\n}\n" 
}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your example input in `file`, you would receive:

```
awk '$1~/\/\// {
>     $1 = "test"
>     gsub(/ /,"_")
>     print "function "$0"() {\n    // test code here...\n}\n"
> }' file
function test_a_user_can_log_in() {
    // test code here...
}

function test_password_is_stored_in_the_database() {
    // test code here...
}
```

Comment: That will print to stdout, right? I would rather use `sed -i` because it will edit the file in-place.

Comment: Yes, but you can redirect to a temp file and do the temp-file-shuffle to simulate an edit in place. (some `awk` allow edit-in-place, but it is non-standard). That is one place that `sed` provides an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I came up with

```sh
function generate_test_cases() {
        while read l; do
                echo $l
                # check if line is a comment
                if [[ $l == //* ]]
                then
                        echo $l
                        # remove //
                        l=${l:2}
                        # replace spaces with underscores
                        l=${l// /_}
                        # append to filename.test.bash
                        echo "function $l() { \n }" >> $1.test.bash
                        echo $l
                fi
        done <$1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative idea using `tr` instead of `sed`:

Assuming that you have read the line to transform into the variable `line`, i.e. the variable contains something like

```
line='// a user can log in'
```

you can generate the function header line in bash by

```
echo "function test$(tr ' ' _ <<<"${line:2}")("
```

`${line:2}` removes the first two characters (`//`), and `tr` replaces each space by an underscore.

As a safety measure, i would **not** edit the file in place. If you make any mistake in the replacement program, you might end up with a corrupt file. If the resulting file really should have the same name as the original one, have your transformer script create a backup copy, and process this backup to overwrite the original file.